# Show $a_n$ is unbounded if $a_n= a_{n-1} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)$ to determine that $a_n$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I wish to determine the limit of $a_n$, where we recursively define:

> $$a_n= a_{n-1} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)$$ where $a_0=1$

I already noticed it is increasing, because 
$$a_n - a_{n-1}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}a_{n-1}>0 $$
Since all terms are strictly positive. (alternatively, we could form a better argument via induction).

---

**edit:**

**Base case:** $a_1 = 2 > 1 = a_0$.

**Hypothesis:** $a_k > a_{k-1}$

**Step:** $a _ {k+1}= a_{k} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)>a_{k-1} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)=a_k $
Therefore $a_n >a_{n-1}$ for all $n$ and the sequence is increasing.

---

I plotted some terms and this seems to grow exponentially, how would I prove it diverges? I think I need to show it is unbounded.I tried the ratio test for sequences but this is inconclusive as the ratio tends to $1$.

Comment: Think about $\log a_n$.

Comment: It doesn't look very exponential from this angle...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convergence+a_n+%3D+a_%7Bn-1%7D+(1+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bsqrt+n%7D)+and+a_0%3D1

Comment: $$ \log(a_n) = \log(a_{n-1}) + \log \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) $$

Comment: You’re asking whether the infinite product $\prod(1+1/\sqrt n)$ converges. This question should be closely relatable to the convergence of $\sum1/\sqrt n$.

Comment: This diverges as the terms do not go to zero fast enough

Comment: Notice that 

$$a_n = \prod_{i=0}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\right) $$
We now consider the logarithm:
$$\log(a_n) = \sum_{i=0}^n \log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\right) $$
But now I need to consider the limit and the argument does not seem as simple

Comment: Try completing by showing that $a_n > n$ for each $n$. This would show that $a_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: **Hint** $$a_n = a_{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=a_{n-2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\\
a_0\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\geq \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=
\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}} \approx e^{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: I already felt like this could be approximated by $e$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to my comment, starting with $$a_n = a_{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=a_{n-2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\\
a_0\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\geq \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=
\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}} \geq ...$$
and applying [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) 
$$...\geq \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}=2^{\sqrt{n}}$$
As a result
$$a_n \geq 2^{\sqrt{n}}$$
and the result follows, i.e. the sequence is unbounded and diverges.

Comment: So the trick is to estimate every term by the smallest term and show that we still get divergence either by Bernoulli's inequality or by comparison with $e^{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Yes, it's a form of a [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Comment: $e$xcellent answer. It feels more like a limit comparison result.

Answer (score 4):

Use $\sqrt n + 1 \geq \sqrt{n+1}, n\in\mathbb N:$

$$a_n = a_{n-1}(1+\frac 1{\sqrt n})\implies a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac 1{\sqrt k})= \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt k + 1}{\sqrt k} \geq \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt k} = \sqrt{n+1}.$$

Comment: That is a satisfying approach.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{i}}\right).$  Now notice that $f(x)=1+x-e^{x/4}\ge 0$ for $x\leq 1.$  Hence $a_n\geq e^{\frac14\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{i}}}\rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Clever, I would need some more practice to come up with something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}a_{n-1}\geq a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$
from which we quickly get
$$a_n\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
which is divergent, since the last sum gives the harmonic series.